# Why Java Pool is not a required component of Oracle SGA?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g, memory, in-memory-database

Why Java Pool is not a required component of Oracle SGA?

As we know SGA has many components, I mean:

- Java Pool
- Shared pool
- Large Pool
- Data Buffer cache
- Others...

I took an exam and I saw that afirmation that i never understood: Java Pool is not a required component of SGA.

Answer (score 2):

Java inside the database is optional. If it is not installed, why waste memory on it?

Since 11.2.0.4, it is possible to "disable" it if patch 20681008 is installed, with the below parameter:

```
"_bug20681008_force_java_pool_zero" = true
```

Starting with 12.2, the below can be used:

```
"_force_java_pool_zero" = true
```